# Multiple solr Shard on single Machine with a master shard exposed to outside

Tags: solr, sharding

Though I am new to distributed search I have fair idea on Sharding and solr cloud. 
Technically When we have bigger index we split it to multiple shards for faster distributed search(Not including Solr Cloud benefits).
I have huge index (obviously same schema) but There is logical separation of data, I call it bucket. Each of these bucket has its own update/deletion/add.

**1st Approach:**
So technically I can create N number of shared depending on the **bucket** count. But this will lead to too many server and will slowdown the search because it has to merge the result.

**2nd Approach:**
To reduce the distribution I can logically combine these buckets and create a less number **parent buckets** which will then reduce the overall shard . But then I will loose some of the advantage related to individual bucket.

**3nd Approach**
I was thinking if I can create something similar to shard of shard. On each machine I will have one parent bucket as shard(Call it Parent Shard) which inter will have multiple child shard hosted on the same solr instance on the same machine (call it as child shard).This will like multiple core in single solr with same schema. In this scenario parent shard will merge the record from each of the child shard by executing queries parallel on child shards and merge it. As it is on the same solr instance I believe it will be faster. I want the parent shared to be empty and just handle merging of result. Is it possible and if so will performance match 2nd Approach. Can someone give me some idea how to implement it I am fine with customizing solr for this implementation.

Comment: I Found a solution for the third approach. I will have multiple core and have empty core with a custom search handler configured. This search handler will merge the data and send the response. This core will be exposed in shard. I am doing a performance and memory analysis between single index verses multiple core.

Comment: Above approach has performance issue